# How To Read bytes.fromhex() From A File in Python

Tags: python, encryption, file-io, formatting, byte

I'm working on a project, and a key thing that I'm stuck on is being able to read in encrypted data from a file. I've done some looking around, and I can't find anything specific about this issue.

Data is encrypted from a Python implementation of DES, and the encryption comes out from this return statement: `return bytes.fromhex('').join(result)`. For example, encrypting `b'This'` gives this as a result:

`b'\xc5lP\x04\x8c\xe2\xa8\x05'`

I then place this encryption into a file (opened as "wb") using `out_file.write(data)`.

My problem is that when I try to read the encrypted data from the file, nothing gets read. The code below shows that I can read in data the way I want when plaintext is used, but not when this formatting of encrypted text is. I need the read-in data as a `bytes` type.

```
with open(filename, "rb") as in_file:
    buffer = in_file.read()
```

Using this on a file with the plaintext `This`, printing `buffer` looks like:

`b'This'`

However, doing this on a file with the encrypted plaintext formed from `bytes.fromhex('')`, printing buffer gives nothing:

`b''`

Are there any suggestions on how to either format the encrypted text to put it into a file so that it can be read, or reading data from a file in this particular format? I'm just not understanding why this format is not being interpreted properly as `bytes` when I read it in from a file.

Comment: You cannot encode your ciphertext using `fromhex`. Encrypted data contains bytes with pseudo-random values. If you use `formhex` on that then you will certainly get data loss.

Comment: None of that makes any sense. First of all, `bytes.fromhex('')` is just a long-handed way of specifying the empty `bytes` object. A much cleaner and shorter way is simply `b''`. Secondly, `infile.read()` will read in the entire file into a `bytes` object if you opened it with `rb`. Perhaps you opened the file with `wb` instead of `rb`? Otherwise, I'll make the usual request: please provide a **complete** example including the parameters of the problem. I should be able to copy-and-paste it into my development environment, run it, and get the same results you're seeing.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes the cipher was not my implementation. It is an open-source implementation of DES that I need to use. However, decrypting the ciphertext in that form gives the original plaintext every time. I don't think there's any data loss.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk as described above, the actual form of the data from the DES implementation is `bytes.fromhex('').join(result)`. So it is not empty data. My problem is that I can't read the bytes from the file when it is placed there already in a `bytes` format

Comment: Please *carefully* re-read what I wrote.